# Why launching iOS App through photos Gallery not work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, photo

I have an issue to launch my app through "photos Gallery" and get the url for image, I use the method bellow to get the url and image from email or browser but I cannot get the url and launch my app through photos Gallery. any idea?

Thanks,

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with share extension. 
here is the link: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-build-an-ios-share-extension-in-swift-4a2019935b2e